# React Native FlatList only responds to touches sometimes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, touch, react-native-flatlist

I have used `FlatList` in multiple places in my app previously without any issues, but now when I created a new one it doesn't seem to register touches/swipes correctly. Only like 1/6 touches seem to register.

See the video here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/NZCtVYX6GLVCQN392

This is how I use the `FlatList`:

```
render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                ...
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.exercises}
                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                        <SetsRepsAndWeightItem exercise={item}/>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                    style={style.list}
                />
            </Container>
        );
}
```

And the `SetsRepsAndWeightItem`:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={style.container}>
                <View style={style.header}>
                    <Text style={style.headerText}>{this.props.exercise.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={style.about}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleSetsPressed}>
                        <StatisticNumber metric="Sets" value={7}/>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleRepsPressed}>
                        <StatisticNumber metric="Reps" value={5}/>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleWeightPressed}>
                        <StatisticNumber metric="kg" value={35}/>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
}

handleSetsPressed = () => {
    console.log("sets pressed");
}

handleRepsPressed = () => {
    console.log("reps pressed");
}

handleWeightPressed = () => {
    console.log("weight pressed");
}
```

Also: the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` elements are not calling their `onPress` functions when they are touched.

The `Container` is as simple as this:

```
export default class Container extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: Proptypes.any,
    backgroundColor: Proptypes.string
  };

  render() {
    const containerStyles = StyleSheet.flatten([
      style.container,
      this.props.backgroundColor ? { backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor } : null,
    ]);

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
            <View style={containerStyles}>
              {this.props.children}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you are making too much work on the render method. Please post your handle methods and the container. Maybe you are making too much logging and it is dragging the screen.

Comment: @sfratini I very much doubt would be the reason, but I updated the question with it. I use the `Container` for the screens with my other `FlatList`s and there are no issues on those.

Comment: What happens if you remove the keyboard dismiss of the parent?

Comment: @sfratini That did fix the scrolling issue :)! Although the buttons within each `SetsRepsAndWeightItem` still don't call their `onPress` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two fixes solved the issues for me:

1. Remove the `onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}` from the `Container` component
2. Move the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` into the `StatisticNumber` component, and pass `onPress` as a prop from `SetsRepsAndWeightItem`